# I am famous, I am in maths , I am the sun. What am I?

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

This is my first question, so feel free to edit. I am open to suggestions.

> Oh! I am so excited!! This is my first puzzle!
>   I can show you where the things are. Ready for a quick game?
>   I am rich you know! I can be usually in a command, or a hat.
>   And...
>   I am famous; I am in maths; I am the sun.
>   Open me... close me, you will get less or more.
>   Guessed it yet? I think it's worth trying for!

Each line represents something. Combining all those things gives you the answer. But the final line is just for the rhyme (I know it's not a good one, but I tried).

Hint:

> It is related to something, every member on every Stack Exchange site uses.

Comment: Is "oh! I am so excited!!this is my first puzzle!" actually part of the puzzle?  If it is, are the lack of space after the "!!" and the odd capitalization  significant?

Comment: First line is the part of puzzle, thanks for editing, the lack of spaces is just my laziness

Comment: I added a hint, I will add another one after some hours

Comment: Each line does NOT represent a thing—each line represents *one or more things*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This seems to be related to

> the symbols on the number keys of a computer keyboard, read left to right. I initially thought each line referred to one key, but now I think each symbolizes a block of consecutive keys.

Oh! I am so excited!! This is my first puzzle!

> Exclamation mark '!'

I can show you where the things are. Ready for a quick game?

> At-sign '@' (on US keyboards) followed by '#' perhaps symbolic of tic-tac-toe (thanks to user IdiotStyle for this suggestion). Or maybe '@' is for the game Nethack, but that's not quick unless the player is unlucky or careless.

I am rich you know! I can be usually in a command, or a hat.

> Dollar sign `$` symbolizing money, followed by '%' used for variable substitution in MS-DOS/Windows commands, followed by '^' (informally called a hat). Or maybe they're all `$` (rich: obvious; command: Unix shell command prompts; hats full of money are a bit of a cliche).

And...

> Ampersand '&'

I am famous, I am in maths , I am the sun.

> Star (asterisk) '*'

Open me... close me, you will get less or more

> Parentheses '(' and ')' followed by '-' and '+' (we're now no longer on the number keys, but still on the same row of the keyboard).

(Thanks to user IdiotStyle for proposing some improvements used above.)

Comment: +1,you are right, but not all the way through. Complete all and I will accept the answer

Comment: The next character after '!' is @. It is normally used as 'at', especially when chatting, to indicate the location/position of something or someone. It might be the answer for "I can show you where the things are".

Comment: I wondered about @ but (1) it doesn't fit the number-keys theme (maybe that was never really a theme, but then the answer seems less satisfying) and (2) the only game it suggests to me is Nethack, which is anything but quick :-).

Comment: Someone suggested (by proposing an edit to my answer) that the hat in the line beginning "I am rich" might be the caret, but I thought each line was referring to a single thing. (And there's a sort of cliche about hats full of money.)

Comment: ... oh, but wait, on some keyboards shift-2 is an @. (But not in the UK where I live. Oops.)

Comment: I initially thought each line was meant to refer to a single key (with a bit of fudge in the last one) but have changed my mind and also incorporated some suggestions in a proposed edit from user IdiotStyle. How does it look now, smriti?

Comment: hey what about ~ symbol or `?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan spot on!!, I will accept the answer, Ya I know I kinda neglected ~, but I will blame it on my laziness yet again :)

Comment: Shift + 2 is '@' on the keyboards we use and I thought it was the standard.

Comment: In so far as there's a standard, it is. There are a lot more US than UK keyboards.

Answer (score 4):

Main credits go to Gareth McCaughan for his answers put me on the right track.

It is:

> Indeed the symbols on the top row of a keyboard from left to right

Oh! I am so excited!! This is my first puzzle!

> This is an exclamation mark '!' as the leftmost symbol. (1)

I can show you where the things are.

> The things are "at" '@' (2)

Ready for a quick game?

> The hashtag '#' is also the playboard for a quick game of Tic Tac Toe. (3)

I am rich you know!

> The Dollar sign "$"(4)

I can be usually in a command

> The percentile symbol '%' (5)

or a hat.

> The hat symbol '^' (6)

And...

> The sign for "and", the ampersand '&' (7)

I am famous, I am in maths , I am the sun.

> A Star is famous, in math the asterisk is a multiplier symbol and the sun is a star. '*' (8)

Open me...

> Opening parenthesis '(' (9)

close me,

> Closing parenthesis ')' (0)

you will get less

> Minus sign '-' (-)

or more

> Plus sign '+'

Comment: +1 for spot on answer, but GarethMcCaughan has done all the research, so I am accepting his answer, sorry

Answer (score 0):

I think you are

> STAR

I can show you where the things are. Ready for a quick game?

> People can be guided by stars for directions

I am rich you know! I can be usually in a command, or a hat.

> Stars can be rich, stars can be in a command on a computer. Hat Full of Stars is an album by Cyndi Lauper.

And...I am famous, I am in maths , I am the sun.

> Stars are famous, common in maths notation, and the sun is a star

Open me... close me, you will get less or more

> Now I'm stuck

Guessed it yet? I think it's worth trying for!

> It's worth aiming for the stars!!!

Comment: nice try! Not the answer I am looking for though